# SQL Server - Query returns bad format

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which returns `nvarchar` format and I need `timestamp`. In the database I have a column with this data type, but for comparison I formate it to string to be able to compare it with timestamp.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT test_run_id, 
       status_timestamp, 
       data_set 
FROM test_runs 
WHERE test_run_id IN (SELECT MAX(test_run_id) AS test_run_id
                      FROM test_runs 
                      WHERE FORMAT(status_timestamp, 'dd-MM-yyyy') = '15-11-2017'
                      GROUP BY data_set)
```

I think there are two options.. to convert `status_timestamp` back to timestamp data type or not to format the column in where condition and the string "15-11-2017" convert to timestamp with milliseconds... `to_timestamp` doesn't work for me

Comment: i removed `MySQL` tag cause `MySQL` <> `Sql-Server`

Comment: Do you have a question? and please define _doesn't work for me_

Comment: **WARNING**: the `TIMESTAMP` datatype in SQL Server has **nothing** to do with a date and time! It's an internal, binary counter - what you're looking for is a `DATETIME2(n)` (date & time) or `DATE` (date only) datatype....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess **Status_timeStamp** column already is in timestamp/DateTime datatype in which case the formatting or the timestamp conversion is not required.

Just use,

```
SELECT test_run_id, status_timestamp, data_set 
FROM test_runs 
WHERE test_run_id IN (SELECT MAX(test_run_id) AS test_run_id
                      FROM test_runs 
                      WHERE status_timestamp = '2017-11-15'
                      GROUP BY data_set)
```

This should work. When you specify the date value in the format **yyyy-mm-dd** mysql automatically converts the value.

Comment: I think this will work if the timestamp contains only info about year, month and day.. but it contains info also about hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.. so when I will do it like status_timestamp = '2017-11-15' , the response is null .. I tried this status_timestamp like '2017-11-15%' to search for substring but doesn't work

Comment: then give the time value as 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format

Answer (score 0):

Your table probably doesn't contain a timestamp column - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx  says  "The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type." - You've probably got a datetime instead, and you're calling it a timestamp. Be careful what you call things, especially if what you call something is not what another developer will call that thing. If in doubt, post the structure of your table in your question

Don't convert the data, just check it using a range. This way any indexes on the column can still be used. Converting data usually prevents indexes being used, and that's bad:

```
SELECT test_run_id, 
       status_timestamp, 
       data_set 
FROM test_runs 
where test_run_id IN (select max(test_run_id) AS test_run_id
FROM test_runs where status_timestamp >= CONVERT(datetime, '20171115', 112) AND status_timestamp < CONVERT(datetime, '20171116', 112)
GROUP BY data_set)
```

I recommend a range, in case your datetime column contains a time as well as a date.

The `CONVERT(datetime, '20171115', 112)` takes a string in `yyyymmdd` format (that's the 112 bit) and turns it into a date. I generally prefer to do this, rather than rely on implicit conversion of string to date, because then I can know for certain that the string is converted to a date, rather than all the table dates being converted to string. You can probably get away with a query that says `WHERE status_timestamp >= '2017-11-15'` for example, as SQLserver will probably implicitly convert the `2017-11-15` string to a date.. I just don't like "probably" when dealing with queries. Explicit is better than implicit